# ngFor - Get item from loop to call it in a function

Tags: angular5, ngfor

I have a table containing the list of feedback. I'm trying to call the function on each looped item.

HTML File:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let fd of feedbacks;let i = index">
   <tr>
     <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td>
     <td>{{ fd.feedback }}</td>
     <td><button (click)="Analyzer(fd.feedback)">Click me!</button></td>
   </tr>
     </ng-container>
```

Attempted action : Set each item as argument to Analyzer() function.

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem?

If you have a function defined in the .ts file

```
Analyzer(feedback: string) { /* .. */ }
```

Then what you have will work

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine! Please make sure you have the method **Analyzer()** defined in your .ts file. Also, I would add as a recommendation that methods should start with a lowercase letter, in your case would be **analyzer()**, but take this just as a recommendation.

Comment: Yes, the function is already defined as you proposed. It works but it returns the result of the last item in every row, cause it's an array. What I'm trying to do, is to return result of each item in each specific row.

Comment: Interesting. Did you try putting the *ngFor in the tr instead of the ng-container? I do not think this may do a difference, but we can try.

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm guessing when you say it returns, it is that the received parameter, meaning (feedback: string) is getting the last row's value. Or, are you referring that the analyzer method does some calculation and then it returns? If the latter is the case, then, could you share the code of the analyzer method?

Comment: Also, did you verify that the string value for the feedback property is different for each feedback object? I am just trying to get a better understanding of the structure of your code, since I do not have all the details.

Comment: Yes, here is the sample of code:                                                        
  Analyser(item:string){
    this.toneAnalyser.TestAnalyser(item).subscribe(res => {
      this.test = res;}) }